# Passing parameters to WEB API Self Hosted Service

Tags: c#, self-hosting

I have a simple client app that talks to a self hosted web api:

```
class Program
{
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080");

        LoadForeman();

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void LoadForeman()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage resp = client.GetAsync("api/foreman").Result;
        resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var foreman = resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<SelfHost.Foreman>>().Result;
        foreach (var f in foreman)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", f.ForeBadge, f.ForeName);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I pass parameters (strings) from the client to the service?

EDIT: WEB API SERVICE

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8080");
        //describes how to access API via HTTP
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        using (HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
        {
            server.OpenAsync().Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does the server expect those strings?  Request parameters?  A JSON object?  Something else?

Comment: This is self hosted web api with the client being a console application. I'll add the main method of the WEB API Service above.

Comment: What I mean is, what are the values you're trying to send and how does the controller expect to receive those values?

Comment: I want to send connection string info. I am not sure how the controller would expect to receive the value. That is part of my question.

Comment: I would think the WebAPI project would know its own connection string, likely pulled from a `Web.config`.  It seems kind of strange that a client would have to send a connection string.  But if it needs to then it could send it like any other string.  Could be a query string parameter (URL-encoded of course), could be part of an object sent to the service, etc.  It's really not clear what you're trying to accomplish here.  Is there something on a WebAPI tutorial you're trying to implement?  How to send values to WebAPI seems like it would be covered by any introductory tutorial.

Comment: The client reaches out to multiple databases for data depending on the situation. It needs to send different connection strings to the WEB API for it to go out and get data.

Comment: It's sounding more and more like this is a *very* broad question of how to use WebAPI at all...  What does your controller look like?  Where does the WebAPI code *use* the value that needs to be sent to it?

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is an old post, but you can pass information to the controller with a custom DelegatingHandler.

i.e:

```
 _config = New HttpSelfHostConfiguration(myUrl)
 _config.MessageHandlers.add(New MyHandler(cs))

Public Class WebApiHandler
    Inherits System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler
    Private ReadOnly _cs As String
    Public Sub New(ByVal cs as String)
        _cs = cs
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function SendAsync(request As HttpRequestMessage, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)
        request.Properties("ConnectionString") = _cs
        Return MyBase.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
    End Function
End Class
```